# inspect.signature: getting different behaviour in python3.3 and python3.4+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3, python-3.5

The "X" of my problem is that I'm trying to write a function that determines whether a callable accepts variable keyword args, the way I did it in python2 was using a call to `getargspec` as follows:

```
if six.PY2:
    # First check if object is callable to make behaviour same as python3
    if not callable(func):
        raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(func))
    try:
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            argspec = inspect.getargspec(func.__call__)
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            # assume function is valid, but weird, fall back to True
            argspec = None
    return not argspec or argspec[2] is not None
```

the problem now is that under python3, the suggested method is using `Signature` objects. However when I try the following:

```
import inspect


class CallableKwargs(object):

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

inspect.signature(CallableKwargs)
```

I get the following error with **Python3.3** only:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "itest.py", line 9, in <module>
    inspect.signature(CallableKwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/inspect.py", line 1449, in signature
    raise ValueError('callable {!r} is not supported by signature'.format(obj))
ValueError: callable <class '__main__.CallableKwargs'> is not supported by signature
```

However, the code I'm writing needs to support both Python3.3 and Python3.5, is there a workaround to this? I tried using `inspect.getfullargspec`, that function unlike `inspect.getargspec` in Python2 doesn't raise a `TypeError`(in 3.4 and 3.5, does raise `TypeError` in 3.3) on passing `CallableKwargs`, however the dict returned does not check the `__call__` method and erroniously returns:

```
FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[],
 kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

in Python 3.4 and Python 3.5, which is again a problem(notice that `varkw=None`).

So, is there something here that I can use and is consistent across both 3.3 and 3.5?

Comment: `CallableKwargs` is callable due to its `__init__` method not its `__call__` method to start with. `__call__` will convert its instances into callables.

Comment: `inspect.getargspec()` on Python 2 doesn't support this scenario either. If you must have Python 3.5 behaviour, I'd just backport it, the source code is available and linked from the documentation.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Oh, ok. Though that helps, I'd prefer to do it using `signature`, why am I not getting one under 3.3?

Comment: @rootavish Few things changed in Python 3.4: https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.4.html#inspect